# Webpack config error: configuration has an unknown property 'postcss'

Tags: webpack, postcss, autoprefixer

I tried to build an angularjs application with webpack. But I can't do it because of the following error.
Using the v2.1.0-beta.21 of webpack, I'm seeing this error.

```
Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration has an unknown property 'postcss'. These properties are valid:
   object { amd?, bail?, cache?, context?, dependencies?, devServer?, devtool?, entry, externals?, loader?, module?, name?, node?, output?, parallelism?, performance?, plugins?, profile?, recordsInputPath?, recordsOutputPath?, recordsPath?, resolve?, resolveLoader?, stats?, target?, watch?, watchOptions? }
   For typos: please correct them.
   For loader options: webpack 2 no longer allows custom properties in configuration.
     Loaders should be updated to allow passing options via loader options in module.rules.
     Until loaders are updated one can use the LoaderOptionsPlugin to pass these options to the loader:
     plugins: [
       new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
         // test: /\.xxx$/, // may apply this only for some modules
         options: {
           postcss: ...
         }
       })
     ]
```

Here's my webpack config showing postcss module. Please check it and let me know what you think. I hope you will carefully review this code and provide me a great solution. I look forward to hearing a good news as soon as possible. Thanks

```
config.module = {
        preLoaders: [{
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            loader: 'remove-flow-types',
            include: path.join(__dirname, '/src/app/stepway')
        }],
        loaders: [{
            // JS LOADER
            // Reference: https://github.com/babel/babel-loader
            // Transpile .js files using babel-loader
            // Compiles ES6 and ES7 into ES5 code
            test: /\.js$/,
            loader: 'babel',
            exclude: /node_modules/
        }, {
            // CSS LOADER
            // Reference: https://github.com/webpack/css-loader
            // Allow loading css through js
            //
            // Reference: https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader
            // Postprocess your css with PostCSS plugins
            test: /\.css$/,
            // Reference: https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin
            // Extract css files in production builds
            //
            // Reference: https://github.com/webpack/style-loader
            // // if wanted css and js into same bundle:
            // Use style-loader in development.
            // loader: isTest ? 'null' : 'style!css!postcss'
            // // if wanted to separate css into another chunk file:
            loader: isTest ? 'null' : ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!postcss-loader')
        }, {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            // // if wanted css and js into same bundle:
            // loader: isTest ? 'null' : 'style!css!postcss!sass'
            // // if wanted to separate css into another chunk file:
            loader: isTest ? 'null' : ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', 'css-loader!postcss-loader!sass-loader')
        }, {
            // ASSET LOADER
            // Reference: https://github.com/webpack/file-loader
            // Copy png, jpg, jpeg, gif, svg, woff, woff2, ttf, eot files to output
            // Rename the file using the asset hash
            // Pass along the updated reference to your code
            // You can add here any file extension you want to get copied to your output
            test: /\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot)$/,
            loader: 'file'
        }, {
            test: /\.json$/,
            loader: 'json-loader'
        }, {
            // HTML LOADER
            // Reference: https://github.com/webpack/raw-loader
            // Allow loading html through js
            test: /\.html$/,
            loader: 'raw'
        }]
    };

    // ISTANBUL LOADER
    // https://github.com/deepsweet/istanbul-instrumenter-loader
    // Instrument JS files with istanbul-lib-instrument for subsequent code coverage reporting
    // Skips node_modules and files that end with .test
    if (isTest) {
        config.module.preLoaders.push({
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: [
                /node_modules/,
                /\.spec\.js$/
            ],
            loader: 'istanbul-instrumenter',
            query: {
                esModules: true
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * PostCSS
     * Reference: https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer-core
     * Add vendor prefixes to your css
     */
    config.postcss = [
        autoprefixer({
            browsers: ['last 2 version']
        })
    ];

    /**
     * Plugins
     * Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#plugins
     * List: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html
     */
    config.plugins = [];

    // Skip rendering index.html in test mode
    if (!isTest && !isProd) {
        // Reference: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
        // Render index.html
        config.plugins.push(
            // new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            //   template: './src/public/index.html',
            //   inject: 'body'
            // }),

            // Reference: https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin
            // Extract css files
            // Disabled when in test mode or not in build mode
            // css bundle file:
            new ExtractTextPlugin('eda.stepway.css'),
            new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
            new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                name: 'vendor',
                filename: 'vendor.bundle.js',
                minChunks: Infinity
            }),
            new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
                options: {
                    context: __dirname,
                    postcss: [
                        autoprefixer
                    ]
                }
            })
        );
    }

    // Add build specific plugins
    if (isProd) {
        config.plugins.push(
            // Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#noerrorsplugin
            // Only emit files when there are no errors
            new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),

            // Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#dedupeplugin
            // Dedupe modules in the output
            new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),

            // Reference: http://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#uglifyjsplugin
            // Minify all javascript, switch loaders to minimizing mode
            new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),

            // Copy assets from the public folder
            // Reference: https://github.com/kevlened/copy-webpack-plugin
            new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
                from: __dirname + '/preview/vendors',
                to: __dirname + '/dist/vendors'
            }]),

            // Reference: https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin
            // Extract css files
            // css bundle file:
            new ExtractTextPlugin('eda.stepway.css')
        );
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, I used webpack v1.12.13 for build

Comment: you aren't allowed to do `config.postcss`. Check the README for postcss: https://github.com/postcss/postcss